# Can't set headers after they are sent after first request only

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, coffeescript

i'm having a specific problem with the error "Can't set headers after they are sent".

The code is this one:

```
create: (request, response, next) ->
socket = @app.socket

#
# This method will be used to call the right method inside
# the emails service.
data = JSON.stringify(
  Object.assign request.body.data, method: 'server'
)

socket.send data

socket.on 'message', (result) =>
  result = JSON.parse(
    result.toString()
  )

  if result.code is 'success'
    @model.insertAsync request.body
      .then (result) ->
        response.json data: result
        return
      .catch next
    return
return
```

I'm using two servers and socket connection to communication between them. When i want create a email, i send a message for this other server and wait for the result, if the result is "success", i send the data back (i'm using Ember, so i need send the data after saving it). Now the problem: when i send the email for the first time everything works normal, when i try for the second time, a error message shows in my terminal:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

According to express, the error is in this line:

```
response.json data: result
```

or in JS:

```
response.json({data: result});
```

The code in pure JS:

```
create: function(request, response, next) {
    var data, socket;
    socket = this.app.socket;
    data = JSON.stringify(Object.assign(request.body.data, {
      method: 'server'
    }));
    socket.send(data);
    socket.on('message', (function(_this) {
      return function(result) {
        result = JSON.parse(result.toString());
        if (result.code === 'success') {
          _this.model.insertAsync(request.body).then(function(result) {
            response.json({
              data: result
            });
          })["catch"](next);
        }
      };
    })(this));
  }
```

Thanks in advance, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely what is happening is you are receiving more than one successful "message" and so it's calling `response.json()` multiple times.

You could fix this by changing `on('message')` to `once('message')` so that the event handler only executes once. However, if that one message is not successful, a response won't be sent. So you may need to either add an `else` to your `if (result.code === 'success')` *or* leave `on('message')` and introduce some sort of guard variable so that the code inside the `if` is only executed once.

Comment: Yeap, that's the problem, i fixed with once. If you don't mind, do you know why this happens? So so strange i think..

Comment: It's because `response.json()` is directly or indirectly trying to write headers (and a body). HTTP only allows one response (one set of headers) for one request.

Comment: Yes, i understand this concept, what i find odd is why my other server is responding two times if i'm just sending one message.